# Make Google Play Game Services' activities full screen (hide status bar)

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is there any way to hide status bar in activities from Google Play Game Services eg. leaderboards screen, achievements screen etc.? If it's possible - how to do it?

Comment: I am also have the same Question. you got the answer ?

Comment: I have similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533430/hiding-the-status-bar-in-android-app-while-google-game-sign-in?noredirect=1#comment41736651_26533430