# Hiding the Status bar in Android app while Google Game sign in

Tags: android, google-play-games

In my Android App, I am using the google play game services with some leaderboards. My app uses the full screen. But when the google play sign in happens or when it shows the leaderboards it is showing the status bar as i have shown in the below mentioned picture. Could you please let me know how to hide it. [image]

Comment: Have you read this: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html ?

Comment: You can't hide it, as this is not part of your game it is part of the GPG service. It is unchangable in order to provide consistency across all games.